# No Snapshot Tab in MTM Test Controller 2015

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests, tfs-2015, microsoft-test-manager

After Setting up Test Controller for TFS 15 RC2 and linking everything with SCVMM, i wanted to create snapshots for our coded UI Environment. But the Snapshot Tab is missing.

Comment: There isn't test controller 2015, do you use test controller 2013? How did you link everything with SCVMM? Did you create SCVMM lab environment in MTM?

Comment: Ok my mistake, yes im using 2013. I have linked the collection to the SCVMM Library and Host, as well as linked the TFS to the SCVMM. i have 3 lab environemnts created, none of them has the snapshot tab.

Comment: Are them SCVMM lab environments or standard lab environments?

Comment: standart lab environments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to create snapshot for standard lab environments. More information, you can refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997438(v=vs.120).aspx) article.

[image]

Comment: thanks, realy missed to look after the environment type, thanks a lot, br